# Find caller for exception? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in FireFox and I notice that a exception is thrown in my Firebug console.
The exception is in a jQuery function, but I have no idea who the caller is.
The webpage has a lot of custom javascript files included with many lines of code.

Is there any trick that I can use to find out from where the call came?

I have tried removing some of the included javascript files, but due to the size of the project and how things are connected, it is limited.

I tried placing a "debugger;" attribute in a javascript file and just stepped through the code, but it doesn't seem that I hit the correct place doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to find the caller is to put a breakpoint in the jquery line where the exception is thrown. Then you will be able to go through the call stack and see how is the first caller.

But be carefull with firebug, sometime when you put breakpoints, you get a different behaviour if you have multiple asynchronous call. If this is your case, use Chrome debugger to manage this.

Comment: The jQuery I have included is minified, so I guess this means that I should try adding the large version to test this approach?

Comment: I didn't know that Firebug renders the script into something more readable.. I put the breakpoint and it was very helpful! Thanks mate